# Error 500 when sending a message to node.js express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I try to transfer data from the form to the server and when transferring an error 500(POST http://localhost:3000/api/message 500 (Internal Server Error)).I went to the network / preview tab and there I see "Something went wrong, try again".I do not know what happened

main file:

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json({extended:true}))
app.use ('/api' , require('./Routes/Message'))
const Port = config.get('port') || 5000
async function start() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.get("MongoURI"), {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex:true
        })
        app.listen(Port, () => console.log("sus"))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

start()
```

Message.js:

```
const {Router} = require("express")
const router = Router()
const {check, validatorResult} = require("express-validator")
const User = require("../models/Message")
router.post('/message', [check("email", "Incorrect email").isEmail()], async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let errors = validatorResult(req)
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                errors: errors.array,
                message: "Incorrect data"
            })
        }
        let {name,email, phone,message} = req.body
        let user = new User({name,email, phone,message})
        await user.save()
        res.status(201).json({message: "Message sent"})
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({message: "Something went wrong, try again"})
    }
})
module.exports= router
```

form:

```
import React from "react";
import  {useState} from 'react'
import "../../css/App.css";
import {useHTTP} from "../../store/api";
export const Form=()=>{
const {loading,request}=useHTTP()
const [form,setForm]=useState({name:"",email:"",phone:"",message:""})
const SendMessage=async ()=>{
  try {
    const data=await request("/api/message","POST",{...form})
    console.log(data)
  }
  catch (e) {

  }
}
const change=(e)=>
{
setForm({...form,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
}
    return (
      <div className="MainFifth-write">
        <h2>text</h2>
        <form method="post">

          <input placeholder="text" required  onChange={change} name="name"/>
          <input placeholder="text"  onChange={change} name="phone" required />
          <input placeholder="text"   onChange={change} name="email" required />
          <br />
          <textarea placeholder="text"  onChange={change} name="message" required />
          <br />

          <input className="agree" required type="checkbox" />
          <label>text</label>
          <br />
          <button onClick={SendMessage} className="submit" type="submit" disabled={loading}>send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
}
```

file with useHTTP:

```
const useHTTP=()=>{
    const [loading,setLoading]=useState(false);
    const [error,setError]=useState(null);
    const request=useCallback( async(url, method='GET', body=null,headers={})=>{
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            if(body) {
                body=JSON.stringify(body)
                headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
            }
            const response=await fetch(url,{method,body,headers})
            const data=await response.json()
            if(!response.ok){
                throw new Error(data.message||"Что-то пошло не так")
            }
            setLoading(false)
            return data
        }
        catch (e) {
            setLoading(false)
            setError(e.message)
            throw e
        }
    },[])
    return {loading,request,error}
}
```

TY all.

Comment: Just `console.log` the error in Message.js's `catch` and then look at your backend's console after the error occurs.

Comment: ty , I just spelled validationResult incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spelled validationResult incorrectly.